# lightdm.conf content erased, now stuck in low graphics mode

Tags: lightdm

This evening I was attempting to disable the guest account and something went awry.

Currently on boot Ubuntu enters low graphics mode. No specific error report.

What did I do? Before this error occurred I added a line of code in lightdm.conf to disable the guest account. I think I may have accidentally erased the contents of lightdm.conf. Not entirely sure.

I troubleshooted for the past hour using various suggestions from other Questions to no avail.

Comment: Please add the contents of your lightdm.conf to your question.

Comment: I assume you meant low graphics mode?

Comment: Yes I meant low graphics mode. My mistake.

As for the contents. How would I check that? I am not able to access the desktop. The most I am able to do from the Ubuntu partition is access the terminal through ctrl+alt+f1 from the low graphics menu.

Comment: I guess you'd have to type in the contents from another PC, not very practical unless you can copy the files to another system.  I'd also love to have a look at your log file, /var/log/lightdm.log.  If you want a short-cut, just use type in the conf file I posted below.

Answer (score 2):

There is an example version of `lightdm.conf` at:

```
/usr/share/doc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.gz
```

You can see it with `zcat /usr/share/doc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.gz`.

Answer (score 1):

We can't do much debugging without your lightdm.conf file, but if you want a minimal version that will work, try this one:

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-session=unity-greeter
allow-guest=false
```

EDIT: For future reference, you can make many changes to lightdm.conf easily and safely with the tool `/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults`, including disabling the guest session.

Try it next time.  Run it without any arguments to see all the options.  `/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -l false` will disable the guest account.

Comment: The file was similar before I edited it. I currently cannot access the desktop. How would I go about editing the file from low graphics mode?

Comment: Control-Alt-F1 to drop to a virtual terminal.  Login, then sudo vi /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

Comment: So did it work?

Comment: I'll have a go at it tomorrow, getting late. Deliver an update then. Thanks for the advice

Comment: You can also try the tool I mention in my post, it can set the session.  I don't know what it will do if the file is totally gone though, but if you're more comfortable with that than vi, give it a shot.  Also run it with sudo.

Comment: @user79318 `vi` may be difficult for novices, so I recommend you use `sudo nano`. Ctrl+O(the letter, not the number) followed by Enter(twice, I think) saves, and Ctrl+X exits.

Comment: So unfortunately the error was more than just debugging lightdm.conf. I ended up just taking everything of value out of Home and doing a clean install. Thanks for the help anyway